# Why does this function keep looping?

Tags: ios, swift, logic, mapkit

```
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
        regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
    MapOutlet.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}
```

This function above within my view controller below continues to run although I never coded any loop in, can someone help spot the incorrect logic.  Here is the rest of the view controller

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class ViewControllerPublic: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()



let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 3.632488, longitude: -117.898886)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)

    // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    // For use in foreground
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: locValue.latitude, longitude: locValue.longitude)
    centerMapOnLocation(currentLocation)
}

let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 2300
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
        regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
    MapOutlet.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}

@IBOutlet weak var MapOutlet: MKMapView!

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: `didUpdateLocations` Update on each location update. and you have called the function, That's why it called on slight location change.

Comment: You could also just expose some UI that allows the user to control the `setUserTrackingMode:animated:` setting and MapView will do everything for your

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never invalidate the `CLLocation manager` so as @Ashish Kakkad said, whenever you get even the slightest location change your function is getting called again. If you don't want this behavior, then after you get a location in `didUpdateLocations` you need to do `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`. Or, if you do want your app to update the map every time the location changes, you may want to think about changing your desired location accuracy.